# Why does printf() formatting not work for a decimal number all 0's?

Tags: c, printing, floating-point, formatting, integer

I can't figure this one out:

```
gettimeofday(&time,NULL);
float stamp = ( (time.tv_sec*1000000)+(time.tv_usec) );

printf("Time Stamp = %08.3f\n",12345678.123);
printf("Time Stamp = %08.3f\n",stamp);
printf("Time Stamp = %08.3f\n",00000000.000);
```

Output:

```
Time Stamp = 12345678.123    
Time Stamp = 637973952.000    
Time Stamp = 0000.000  //?
```

How is it that the last printf does not print 8 0's before the decimal place (only prints 4)?

My goal is to printf a time stamp with 8 digits to the left of the decimal place and 3 to the right. (All the time, if the number is smaller, insert padded 0's).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "8" to the left of the decimal point is NOT the number of digits to print to the left of the decimal point, but the TOTAL number of digits to print, including the decimal point itself.  If you want to see 8 digits to the left of the decimal point AND 3 digits to the right (and the decimal point), you should use

```
printf("Time Stamp = %012.3f\n", stamp);  // 8 to the left + 1 for d.p. + 3 to the right = 12
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: one doubt,  if it's `the TOTAL number of digits to print,` then why should it print `12345678.123` total `12` digits for `%08.3f`? here we only give `8` digits.

Comment: @Jayesh Because the number that comes after `%` is only a minimum width. If the number requires more to be printed correctly, more characters are used. “An optional minimum field width. If the converted value has fewer characters than the field width, it is padded with spaces (by default) on the left”. The `0` in `%08.3f` indicates to pad with zeroes instead but the “if the converted value has fewer …” condition applies nonetheless. C99 7.19.6.1:4

Answer (score 1):

`printf` format specifier follows this prototype:

```
%[flags][width][.precision][length]specifier
```

*Width* means desired total length, and *precision* is counted as part of it (that includes dot if present).
To solve your problem, you should use format `%012.3f`.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're confusing precision marker **'.'** with field width specifier.
**0000.000** contains **8** characters. Had you asked for **10** you would've got **000000.000** (**10** characters including the dot).

Also check down below for more information

> A zero **'0'** character indicating that zero-padding should be used
>   rather than blank-padding. A **'-'** overrides a **'0'** if both are used;
>
> Field Width: An optional digit string specifying a field width; if the
>   output string has fewer characters than the field width it will be
>   blank-padded on the left (or right, if the left-adjustment indicator
>   has been given) to make up the field width (note that a leading zero
>   is a flag, but an embedded zero is part of a field width);
>
> Precision: An optional period, **'.'**, followed by an optional digit
>   string giving a precision which specifies the number of digits to
>   appear after the decimal point, for **e** and **f** formats, or the maximum
>   number of characters to be printed from a string; if the digit string
>   is missing, the precision is treated as zero;

Comment: `Had you asked for 10 you would've got 000000.000 (10 characters including the dot).`  So why it print 12 digits `12345678.123` when `8` characters given?

Comment: That example is for the number 0.0 I've also explained the other case. Next time before you down vote try reading and actually understanding the given answer :)

Comment: yes i already read it and how you say that in second case you explained it? Can you elaborate it?

Comment: @Jayesh So what would **you** print for `12345678.123` with the format `%08.3f`?

Comment: @Jayesh I know you read it but the problem is you didn't understand it. it says "Field Width: An optional digit string specifying a field width; if the output string has fewer characters than the field width it will be blank-padded on the left" in your case the number has more characters than field width so it outputs normally. It is sad that I had to quote my own answer on the comments.

Comment: @TamerTas ok so you said that `if the output string has fewer characters than the field width it will be blank-padded on the left" in your case the number has more characters than field width so it outputs normally.` . but in OP's question `00000000.000` is not contain enough character? why it should blank-padded  at left side?

Comment: @Jayesh 'why it should blank-padded at left side?' I don't understand what you are trying to say blank character or zero character or something else it's up to you the OP used zero characters for padding you can choose something else.

Comment: @PascalCuoq It print right but this answer say that according field width it print characters (ex. For `10` (%10.3f) then it will print `000000.000`).Here total `10` character printed including `.` `6` zeros left to `.` and `3` zeros right to `.`. So if it print according field width then how for `8` field width it print total `12` characters `12345678.123`.

Comment: @TamerTas Ok.. If OP used zero for padding then also here `00000000.000` contain enough character.So why should it not print as normally?

Comment: @Jayesh In `printf("%08.3f",0.0)`, the output is padded **with zeroes** until it is 8 characters long. `12345678.123` cannot fit with 3 digits after the decimal point in 8 characters, so the result is longer. What did you expect `printf` to do, print a truncated result?

Comment: @PascalCuoq Ok so you mean that If `print` find length greater then field width with not character same as padding character then it leave it as it is and print normally. But if it find padding character (left to non padding character ) which cross field length boundary then it will discard it up to non padding character as well as up to field width . right?

Answer (score 0):

if you need print 8 0's try with:

```
printf("Time Stamp = %012.3f\n",0.0);
```